# User friendly term for "Input Field"?

Tags: user-interface, user-input

My web application include an online editor where the user drags elements such as "text", "picture", etc from a toolbar into the canvas.

One of those elements is an "Input Field" that other users will fill out.

I'm trying to think of a user friendly term for this other than "Input Field" and I'm coming up blank. Maybe "Input Box", or "Form Box", but I'm still not really feeling it.

The target audience would be ~16-21 year olds, primarily girls. I've asked a few and "Input Field" doesn't really mean much to most of them, answers range from "the bit where you fill stuff in" to "text box".

Apologies if this is the wrong section of the site for this question. I felt UX.SE was more appropriate but I went and took a look at the questions there and its very interface/design orientated.

Comment: What does the input field look like? What does it do?

Comment: A resizable box that users can enter freeform text into. Think of the app like a WYSIWYG web page editor and this is a text input form field that the 'admin' creates and other users will fill out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about how it was implemented. Name it from the user's perspective. If it serves one clear, simple purpose, then name it that. "Code entry box." "Design box.", etc.

If not, then just go with text box, which is an incredibly clear name and something that mostly everyone has heard.

Comment: Its purpose is quite generic and user-definiable (i.e. can be used for pretty much anything they want it to be used for).

On the other hand, I have split some of the other controls into things like "text" and "text paragraph" because even though they're essentially the same thing I thought it was better to make it clear to a user exactly how they should structure things. So maybe I'll do with this too.

Thanks for the input (get it, hah).

Answer (score 1):

A text box would be the safest option. A novice user would understand at the very least text goes here. Perhaps group that control in a header called User Input Controls.